# Why should variable has public or private or protect but function should not in a class

Tags: php, class, oop

I what to know why can not I able to define a variable in the class without any thing ? *(public, private, protect)*

why this has syntax error ?

```
class myclass {
  $var = 'anythig';
}
```

But this is ok:

```
class myclass {
  function test() { // code here }
}
```

And finally why it is possible to I define a var without anything in function ?

```
class myclass {
  function test() {
   $var = 'anything'; // it has not anythig (public, privare, protect)
  }
}
```

Comment: Because a property needs a visibility. And the function just has public as default if you don't define it

Comment: @Rizier123 Aha I see, but just why variable has not default ? :) **Edit:** and why a variable in a function dont needs anythig ?

Comment: Can't tell you that, that is just how PHP works; (A variable in a method is a local variable, so it's not a class property and can't have a visibility) Also see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: @Rizier123 A variable in a method is local mean only used in the its method ? And not anywhere else?

Comment: Exactly. That the same as you have a normal function not in a class definition and the variable in it can only be accessed in the function itself

Comment: @Rizier123 aha allright. (sorry for asking again) can you tell me how should I call a class ? e.g. I have two class in one script, now I want to call the first class, what should I do ? tnx

Comment: Do you mean you have 2 classes with the same name in 2 files ? Or do you just have 2 classes with different names?

Comment: different names but in one file !

Comment: And your problem is how to instantiate them?

Comment: with your question I got it .. :) thanks (I'm newcomer in OOP)

Comment: You're welcome. Also see:  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: @Rizier123 really sorry for asking again (this is the end), `static` is the same with `private` from the perspective of scope ? and these are different from the perspective of keeping the values ?

Comment: No, static an non-static doesn't have to do anything with the scope. It's a question when *already* you can access the methods. I would recommend you just to watch some tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use any of the programming languages, you should know the [rules](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php), otherwise, the behavior of the program will come strange; for example as in your case, while declaring functions in a class, omitting the visibility keywords implies the function will have the `public` visibility.

About the [property visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#language.oop5.visibility-members):

> Class properties **must** be defined as `public`, `private`, or `protected`. *If
>   declared using `var`, the property will be defined as `public`.*

And about the [method visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#language.oop5.visiblity-methods):

> Class methods **may** be defined as `public`, `private`, or `protected`.
>   *Methods declared without any explicit visibility keyword are defined
>   as `public`.*

And finally about the defining [variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php), I believe you need to read about the [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

---

As per request, about the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095220/why-should-variable-has-public-or-private-or-protect-but-function-should-not-in#comment50206989_31095220) above regarding `static` vs `private`:

`static`ness of a class member is intended to deal with the **lifetime** of the matter (the matter exists regardless of existence of any instance of a class), while `private`ness is about the **visibility** of the matter (for example: the existent matter cannot be accessed when it has the `private` visibility.)

The two are different concepts and are not mutually exclusive (you may use them together.) Mixing these concepts, makes me believe that you're in an urgent need of reading some [OOP materials](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Comment: Very nice answer. (Maybe you want to include this comment as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095220/why-should-variable-has-public-or-private-or-protect-but-function-should-not-in#comment50206989_31095220)